# How to import IBM Bluemix Watson speech-to-text in Choregraphe?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, nao-robot

Currently, I am doing a project about Nao Robot. I am having problem with importing the python class file into choregraphe. So anyone knows how to do this?

*Error message*

> [ERROR] behavior.box :**init**:8 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_127183361‌​6__root__RecordSound‌​_3__RecSoundFile_4: ALProxy::ALProxy Can't find service:

Comment: Can you please add your code ([Minimal, Working and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and the error message you get?

Comment: [ERROR] behavior.box :__init__:8 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_1271833616__root__RecordSound_3__RecSoundFile_4:  ALProxy::ALProxy
 Can't find service:

Comment: What is your email? as the file is too big

Comment: Well, if you show it only to me, the idea of SO (using the community) is a bit lost of course. Have you googled the error message, for example [this error which seems to be your problem](https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/forum/box-creation-fail-alproxy-cant-find-services-alvisionrecognition-almemorywatcher-alaudio-1617)?

Comment: You need a real robot to record sound.

Comment: Kamal is right, you can't record audio without running the code on a physical robot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any path to the PYTHONPATH environment variable from within your behavior. However, this has bad side effects, like:

- If you forget to remove the path from the environment right after importing your module, you won't know anymore where you are importing modules from, since there is only one Python context for the whole NAOqi and all the behaviors.
- For the same reason (a single Python context), you'll need to restart NAOqi if you change the module you are trying to import.